# Optimal way to decide Blackjack play with a soft score

Tags: probability, card-games, gambling

I am designing a Blackjack AI such that it would try to play optimally each hand against the dealer.

When I'm having a hard score the algorithm is easy: as long as my risk of busting is lower than the dealer's risk of busting (based on its visible card) I will hit, otherwise stand.

My problem is when I have a soft score. If both scores are under 21, I will have two probabilities of busting based on each version. I do not know however which score should I keep track of.

For example, if I have a soft 21, even though I have a 0% risk of busting the lower score on my next hit, it is better to stand since 21 is a very good score.

On the other hand, if I have a soft 15, it might be better to hit against a dealer's 2, even though the risk of the higher score going over 21 is larger than the risk of the dealer going bust with a 2 showing.

Could you please tell me if there is another parameter that should be considered regarding the soft scores (preferably easy to calculate)? If so, how should I use it on top of the bust probabilities?

N.B.
The only two actions I am able to do are hitting and standing. I am not using any other actions such as doubling down, splitting or surrendering.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I don't classify blackjack as an AI project. Second of all you seem to consider the probability of busting only. What about not busting but winning because of greater score?

In the soft(15) case the player always hits because there is no risk of busting but there is some probability of improving his score. Against all dealer up cards.

If you want to get more into this I can instruct you as to how you'd do it.

Also you might find interesting my solution [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2985886/can-anyone-confirm-expectations-for-the-game-of-blackjack?noredirect=1#comment6161797_2985886) for the complete stand/hit/double/split case.